# I have a error in MySQL Function, trying to declare a local variable getting an error

Tags: mysql

Creating a  function that will add account, acount email is a different table, it allows one to add several email accounts.
Error
SQL query:

CREATE FUNCTION ADD_ACCOUNT( email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255) ) 
    RETURNS TINYINT(1)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE LAST_INSERTED_ID INT DEFAULT 0
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4, DECLARE LAST_INSERTED_ID INT DEFAULT 0;

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ADD_ACCOUNT;
CREATE FUNCTION ADD_ACCOUNT( email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255) ) 
    RETURNS TINYINT(1)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE LAST_INSERTED_ID INT DEFAULT 0;
            INSERT INTO usr() VALUES ();
            ID = LAST_INSERTED_ID();
            INSERT INTO `email`(`ref_id`, `value`) VALUES( ID , email );
            INSERT INTO `password`(`ref_id`, `value`) VALUES( ID, password );
            RETURN ID
        END
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: Error
SQL query:


CREATE FUNCTION ADD_ACCOUNT( email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255) ) 
 RETURNS TINYINT(1)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE LAST_INSERTED_ID INT DEFAULT 0
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You need to define the delimiters before creating a functoin/procedure in mysql